# How we find Latest Date value and update in another column in Sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have thee column were date values are there I have to update fourth column with Latest date value

So please help me to write update query for that in Sql server:

```
   Date1       Date2        Date3      Latest Date
11/24/1991   1/14/2003    11/24/1991    1/14/2003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE  TableName
SET     LatestDate = ( SELECT   CASE WHEN Date1 >= Date2
                                          AND Date1 >= Date3 THEN Date1
                                     WHEN Date2 >= Date1
                                          AND Date2 >= Date3 THEN Date2
                                     WHEN Date3 >= Date1
                                          AND Date3 >= Date2 THEN Date3
                                     ELSE Date1
                                END
                     )
```

and don't forget to add you condition

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Date1 >= Date2 AND Date1 >= Date3 THEN Date1
        WHEN Date2 >= Date1 AND Date2 >= Date3 THEN Date2
        WHEN Date3 >= Date1 AND Date3 >= Date2 THEN Date3
        ELSE                                        Date1
    END AS Latest_Date
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way also :-

```
Set Nocount On;

---- preparing test data
Declare @Dates Table
(
     PrimaryIdKey   Int Identity(1,1)
    ,Date1          Date
    ,Date2          Date
    ,Date3          Date
    ,LatestDate     Date
)

Insert Into @Dates(Date1,Date2,Date3) Values
('11/24/1991','1/14/2003','11/24/1991')
----End :: preparing test data

Update  dp
Set     dp.LatestDate = d.DateValues
From    @Dates As dp
        Join
        (
            Select   d.PrimaryIdKey
                    ,Max(d.DateValues) As DateValues
            From    (
                        Select  d.PrimaryIdKey, d.Dates, d.DateValues
                        From    @Dates
                        UnPivot
                        (
                          DateValues
                          For Dates in (Date1, Date2, Date3)
                        ) d
                    ) As d
            Group By d.PrimaryIdKey
        ) As d On dp.PrimaryIdKey = d.PrimaryIdKey

Select   PrimaryIdKey
        ,Date1
        ,Date2
        ,Date3
        ,LatestDate
From    @Dates As d
```